Smartphone with SIM card slot and data network transmitter/receiver
I was wondering whether it would be possible to have a smartwatch that had a SIM card slot and a data network transmitter/receiver.
This is because, some smartphone apps, on some smart watches, may benefit from such a configuration.
For instance, there may be things that require a more permanently placed app, that monitors, continuously, and alerts the user, even certain conditions happen.
The smartwatch, may, indeed, be a the only viable solution for such applications, that may not be usable in smartphones because the smartphone can be far, out of reach, ... or just, simply, left around.
This would apply in particular to smartwatches that were waterproof, making the placement, on the wrist, more or less permanent (unless the strap caused problems such as rashes, or discomfort (in which case it would just be the case of getting a better watch).
The waterproofness in this case would have to cater to a good sim card slot mechanism that did not permit the sim card slot to get wet, and the battery charging connector would have to be such that it did not rust, while, getting in contact with water.
The phone could not employ a really long cable to keep the cable attached to the wrist while asleep, as this would be unsafe. The user would have to take the watch off at night, but a wireless charging device would be ideal.
The smartwatch could still and might even need to connect to a smartphone or computer via WiFi, and this could be as usual part of the smartwatch solution.
It might even be cool to have it as a solution for certain types of pets, which might benefit from an Android IoT device that could be worn.
The question, I wanted to ask, is, is all of this, (with an Android smartphone being sim card and transmitter/receiver capable, (and waterproof) at all possible)?
Thanks.

It's a bit unclear if you're talking about a standalone smartwatch, not paired with a 'phone. You use "smartphone" in several places where you seem to be talking about the watch. Could you edit the question for clarity, please?
